# GTK: How can I fix this problem: Could not load a pixbuf from /org/gtk/libgtk/icons/16x16/status/image-missing.png

Tags: gtk, executable, pixbuf

I want to get an executable on Windows from my GTK program which can work even if you've not install GTK on you're computer. I've tried to get an installator with inno setup and I copied all dll that I need, but I get this message error on the terminal:

```
(TPGTK+.exe:13972): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:22:02.461: Could not load a pixbuf from /org/gtk/libgtk/icons/16x16/status/image-missing.png.
This may indicate that pixbuf loaders or the mime database could not be found.
**
Gtk:ERROR:../gtk+-3.24.29/gtk/gtkiconhelper.c:494:ensure_surface_for_gicon: assertion failed (error == NULL): Failed to load /org/gtk/libgtk/icons/16x16/status/image-missing.png: Unrecognized image file format (gdk-pixbuf-error-quark, 3)
Bail out! Gtk:ERROR:../gtk+-3.24.29/gtk/gtkiconhelper.c:494:ensure_surface_for_gicon: assertion failed (error == NULL): Failed to load /org/gtk/libgtk/icons/16x16/status/image-missing.png: Unrecognized image file format (gdk-pixbuf-error-quark, 3)
```

Comment: I have the same problem, have you managed to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

install gtk runtime from here: https://github.com/tschoonj/GTK-for-Windows-Runtime-Environment-Installer/releases.